# json response through MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi, mongodb-.net-driver, webapi

When the below API method is called through the API

```
        public IActionResult FirstStudent()
        {
         var collection = this.database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("students");
            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("RollNo", "1");
            var document = collection.Find(filter).First();          
            var firstStudent= document.ToJson();
            return Ok(firstStudent);
        }
```

the response has Content-Type as text/plain.
I need the Content-Type as application/json.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `return JsonResult(firstStudent)`

Comment: I am getting error: 
Non-invocable member 'JsonResult' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: my bad, try `return new JsonResult(firstStudent)`

Comment: I am getting
"{ \"_id\" : \"5e54f99a045dba534831a1a2\", \"RollNo\" : \"1\", \"name\" : \"Johnson\"}"
I rather wanted
{ "_id" : "5e54f99a045dba534831a1a2", "RollNo" : "1", "name" : "Johnson"}

Comment: added a working answer below

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing to do would be to create a student model and simply return an ok result with the student model like this:

```cs
public class Student
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int RollNo { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public IActionResult FirstStudent()
{
    var collection = this.database.GetCollection<Student>("Student");
    var filter = Builders<Student>.Filter.Where(s => s.RollNo == 1);
    var document = collection.Find(filter).First();
    return Ok(document);
}
```

Comment: I can not create a class, the parameters could vary dynamically. Any other solution?